# JSF элемент сделать недоступным

Tags: java, html, css, jsf

Привет я junior-java приходится работать с JSF в нём я как в балете(никак).

Гуру и любители **JSF** нужна ваша помощь!

Есть textPanel:

```
<ss:textPanel title="Комментарии" icon="fa fa-comments">  
 <ui:fragment rendered="true">  ***       
 </ui:fragment>
```

и для её элемента(кнопка "Добавить комментарий") я хочу изменить свойство из обычного в недоступный. нужную(как я пологаю) строчку я пометил звёздочками***.

хочу получить что-то в вроде:

```
<ui:fragment rendered="true" disabled="true">
```

но вместо **disabled** что-то рабочее.

**я вероятно вопрос даже неправильно задаю вопрос, тыканье носом в азы и пинание за непонимание истин приветствуется!**

до:
[image: как есть сейчас]
после:
[image: вот примерно так должно получиться]

Comment: за целый день ни одного плюса/минуса или комментария... может понедельник? ЛЮДИ АУ ВЫ ЗДЕСЬ?
**Упростил код для наглядности**

Comment: Для кнопки используется fragment, а не button? Зачем?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev да как я понял кнопка это часть элемента JSF а сам элемент это блок+кнопка+текстовый редактор который появиться после нажатия кнопки

Comment: Что-то мешает устанавливать атрибут `disabled` и/или класс `customDisabled` именно на кнопку, а не содержащий её фрагмент?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev так и сделал: нашел реализацию кнопки, добавил туда атрибут buttondisabled:boolean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел реализацию кнопки, добавил туда атрибут `buttondisabled:boolean`.

tnx to @SergeyGornostaev